# Counting distinc field values in regex aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents in the following form stored in the elasticsearch:

```
{ "mid" : "", "fun" : "", "user" : "", "jobid" : "", ...}
```

I want to aggregate these documents based on first 3 fields and was successful doing that by this query:

```
{
  "size" : 0,
  "aggs": {
    "username": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "minion_id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "mid"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "network": {
              "filter": {
                "regexp": {
                  "fun": "(ip|network).*"
                }
              }
            },
            "service": {
              "filter": {
                "regexp": {
                  "fun": "service.*"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since I want to group values in the `fun` field based on some patterns I used regex for this field (unlike the other fields that their exact values is intended).

Now my question is this: How can I count number of documents by their distinct values in the `jobid` field?

Take these documents as an example:

```
{ "mid" : "a", "fun" : "ip.a", "user" : "user1", "jobid" : "1", ...}
{ "mid" : "a", "fun" : "network.a", "user" : "user1", "jobid" : "1", ...}
```

As you can see they are put in the same group because their pattern for `fun` field is the same. Using my query gives `2` as the result but I want to return `1` since they have the same value for their `jobid` field.

Thanks.

Comment: you can add terms aggregation on jobid?

Comment: I've tried that, it doesn't work the way I want.